# Umbraco user forget password?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I m admin of a Umbraco CMS, we don't have access to code.

A user changed his password and forget. I tried to log in as admin and resetting passwrod but I just discovered that link is not working.

Can you please guide how I reset password for that user ? Even there is no link if forget password. Is there a way to reset in DB without modifying configuration files ?

EDIT
attaching screen short. In admin panel under Users section Change Your Password link is not working. Please see its highlighted areas.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the admin interface go to the user section select the user in the user navigation tree and click the change password link(is it this link that is not working?), which should show two new text boxes "change password and confirm password" remember to hit save when done.

It can be done using the database as well change the hashed password in the umbracoUser table to a hash of a password that you know. This forum have some ideas of hashed passwords.

http://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/4790-ouch-forgot-admin-password-how-to-reset?p=2

Comment: yes in admin > users section Change password link is not click able. Please see my edit.

Comment: Weird is there any errors in the javascript console or in the umbraco.log?

Comment: +1 for @Kedde - There should certainly be an error in the javascript console that would be useful in troubleshooting this issue.  If you are not concerned with fixing the error and you have access to the SQL database for this site, then follow the link provided in Kedde's original answer and modify the appropriate table to change the password to a hash of a password you already know.